# SceneKit: Reference node generating error [SCNKit ERROR] failed to resolve referenced scene at url

Tags: xcode, scenekit, scnnode

Adding a reference node to a scene works in the Xcode Scene Editor, meaning the reference node appears in the scene.

Yet when running the app on a device, the node does not appear and the following error is generated:

```
[SCNKit ERROR] failed to resolve referenced scene at url file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/33EBF1BC-6539-4807-8168-610831ACF725/Test.app/Test/Test.scn
```

Comment: Are your scene and referenced scene in the same scnasset catalog?

Comment: @toyos possibly not. the tutorial didn't mention anything about scnasset catalogs when explaining reference nodes so will need to dig into this. is this a new requirement for using reference nodes?

Comment: @toyos this fixed the problem. please post as an answer so you can receive credit. thanks for making scenekit. it's awesome!